# get back a response from a PHP page and use it in javascript after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am doing an ajax call and everything is working fine the script that i am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sortable').sortable({
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).effect("highlight");

        //getting the id of the list element being moved and then 
        //we'll send it to the db for its id validation and
        //updating the db upon drag and drop
        var id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
        //alert(id);

        var pos = ui.item.prevAll().length;//prevAll().length
        var position = ++pos;
        //alert("Moved to position: " + position );//+ "from: " + id);
        //var x = ui.offset.left;
        //var y = ui.offset.top;
        //alert("left: " + x + "top: " + y);

        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php", 
            data: {
                position: position, 
                id: id
            }
        }); /*, success:function(result){alert(result);}*/
        /* $.ajax({
            url: "save.php", 
            data: {
                x: x, 
                y: y
            }
        });*/ // data: {x: 'x', y: 'y'}  ------->> for coordinates if needed*/

        $(ui.item).effect("highlight");
      }
    });
})
```

I have a PHP page that is using the values sent and making the required changes in the DB. 
I want to know how to get return values back from the PHP script and use it on the calling page via javascript. The PHP code is:

```
$id1 = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $pos1 = $_REQUEST['position'];//position where the element has been dragged to

    $query = "select * from tab where id='$id1'";
    $t = mysql_query($query) or die("nothing found in the database for the provided id. ".mysql_error());

    if($t)
    {
        $r = mysql_fetch_array($t) or die("data could not be fetched from the DB ".mysql_error());
        $r[0];//id of the dragged <li>element = $id1
        $r[1];//its original position

        $e = "select * from tab where original='$pos1'";

        $y = mysql_query($e) or die("ERROR. ".mysql_error());
        $u = mysql_fetch_array($y) or die("data could not be fetched from the DB for the replaced element. ".mysql_error());                
        $id2 = $u[0];//id of the place where the dragged <li> element was dropped
        $u[1];//original position of the place where the dragged <li> element was dropped

        $temp1 = $r[1]; 
        $temp2 = $u[1]; 

        $temp = $temp1;
        $temp1 = $temp2;
        $temp2 = $temp;

        $up = "update tab set original='$temp1' where id='$id1'";
        $q = mysql_query($up) or die("I query not done. ".mysql_error());

        $up = "update tab set original='$temp2' where id='$id2'";
        $q = mysql_query($up) or die("II query not done. ".mysql_error());
        //echo"id1: " .$id1 ." id2: " .$id2 ." r[1]: " .$temp1 ." u[1]: " .$temp2;
```

Please help me out. I am new to AJAX, so I don't know much about it.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're not capturing the ajax response? you had a success function but commented it out.  Your code snippet does a lot more than you are asking about - keep dumbing it down until it has just the pieces you are concerned with -- this will help you, and it will help others answer.

Comment: try `echoing something` in ajax file .. and after that `alert(result)` in `ajax success`.. check what it returns

Comment: I need to store the returned value in a javascript variable.....
how do i do that??
@DrLivingston

Comment: In the success function save the value to a global variable (defined outside of the ajax call) that you can get to from other places.  But more likely you just want to do whatever work you want to do with the returned value inside of the success function.

Answer (score 0):

use `json_encode` onyour PHP

```
//$array is value you want to return.
echo json_encode($array);
```

or if you want to echo not from array, you must echo json format.